# Broken Wordpress (white screen of death) after accidently deleting plugin from FTP

Tags: wordpress

I managed to delete an active plugin folder from my wordpress FTP and now the site is giving a white screen of death.

I found a copy of the folder in my backups and re-uploaded it but the site is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all plugins directly from DB. [Something like this](http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/)

Then try if wordpress works. After that install plugins one by one and also install this which you manually delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the plugins folder through ftp to plugins_old, then refresh wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/deactivate-plugin-using-phpmyadmin/

If you follow these steps, it will help you deactivate only that plugin which is causing your site to fail. Once this is done your site will probably be back up and you can re-activate that plugin.